# Add multiple libs into Eclipse-IDE for a CDT-project

Tags: c++, eclipse

I want to add multiple libraries to an existing C++ project on Eclipse. I could add one at a time by selecting the option `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries(-l)`. What is a better way to add multiple library files?

By the way, this question had already been asked on [this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575678/eclipse-cdt-add-multiple-libraries) a long time back. And the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18987680/5095879) to that old questions was a work around which is what I am using right now.

I was just wondering, if there is a better way to do so instead of modifying `.cproject` xml.

Comment: It seems that Eclipse CDT development has been stall for quite a long time. So there is no new workarounds for this matter. Managing project settings is still a dull repetitive task. And there is still no way to export / import settings (except for includes).

Comment: @VTT You can [see here that Eclipse CDT is a very active project](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.cdt). Are there any bug reports from you that you refer to?

Comment: Just pasting (Ctrl+V) multiline text into the _Libraries(-l)_ field (instead using the _Add..._ button to add a single line/library) works for me.

Comment: Thank you, @howlger. I never knew it was that simple. Do you mind adding it as an answer? I will accept it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the *Add...* button for each individual library, **multiple libraries can be pasted** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) **as multiline text** (one library per line) into the *Libraries (-l)* field.